# Dominoes is it on-topic?

Tags: discussion, top-7, on-topic

Games which has no cards or boards but it is played like a board game over a table should be on-topic?

For me it should be. Games like that has the same mechanics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Board and Card Games" is a handy descriptor but we should not limit ourselves strictly to games with actual boards or actual cards.  Anything that plays like a board game, regardless of components, is on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

Dominoes is to scrabble as Dominion is to Agricola.  Just a different form factor IMHO.